# How to vertically center a child element of arbitrary size inside a floated parent element (of known size)?

Tags: css, css-float, center, vertical-alignment

How to vertically center a child element *of arbitrary size* inside a *floated* parent element (of known size)?

`display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` no longer seems to work when the element is floated.

**I created an SSCCE here: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/center-vertically-inside-float**

[Without float](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/center-vertically-inside-float#without-float), everything works as it should. But [as soon as the parent element is floated](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/center-vertically-inside-float#with-float), the vertical alignment fails.

Any ideas how to work around this?

**Edit:** I should’ve added that the child elements are supposed to be images. In my example page I’m using paragraphs, since I assumed I could apply whatever CSS those `p` elements needed to `img` elements with `display: block;` as well. (Fail.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to [porneL’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985285/how-to-vertically-center-a-child-element-of-arbitrary-size-inside-a-floated-paren/1985489#1985489), I found the solution to my problem.

In my SSCCE I used paragraphs as child elements (and porneL gave the correct answer as far as that goes), but what I really needed were **images**. Turns out this needs a little bit of additional CSS:

```
div { width: 780px; height: 200px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; float: left; }
 div img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: You can remove `display: table-cell;` from there. `float` forces block display (same as `position:absolute`) — http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: This did the job for me to build a gallery out of a ul that can cope with landscape and portrait images:

.multiline-gallery {
    width: 40em;
}

.multiline-gallery li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    height: 234px;
    width: 234px;
    margin: 1.1875em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 234px;
}

Answer (score 3):

If it's one-liner, then set `line-height` of `p` to height of the container.

Comment: Your answer works for paragraphs (block level elements), which is what I asked for :) Thanks!
Ok, so I guess my SSCCE was a bit *too* simple to demonstrate my real problem. The child element is not supposed to be a paragraph, but an image (of arbitrary height), which requires some additional CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Float disables table-cell, because cells can’t be floated. So basically I would recommend the standard stuff – using floated shim technique or absolute positioning.

Comment: The problem is that absolute positioning cannot be used on the child element, since its size varies.